# No didSelectRowAtIndexPath() in tableView when editing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I want to call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()`, but the event won't be fired, when I'm in edit-mode. This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated:true)
    let data = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
...
}

@IBAction func updateButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    toggleEditing()
}

func toggleEditing() {
    if self.editing {
        super.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        self.title = "Sicherung"
    } else {
        super.setEditing(true, animated: true)
        let cancelBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Fertig", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "stopEdit:")
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancelBarButton
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        self.title = "Sicherung bearbeiten"
    }
}

func stopEdit(sender: AnyObject) {
    super.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    let cancelBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Bearbeiten", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "toggleEditing")
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancelBarButton
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
}
```

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` is only called when `self.editing == false`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:): "_This method isn’t called when the editing property of the table is set to YES (that is, the table view is in editing mode)_"

Comment: uupps, don`t see this! Any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICS, you problem is that, on your table view, `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` is set to `NO` (or `false`, if you're using Swift).

Comment: Arthur Gevorkyan, that´s it! Many THX!

Comment: So, apparently the documentation is outdated then. Nice find :)